# Same Image in Multiple product with feeds

Tags: commerce, feeds

I like to upload a lot of commerce product from a csv file and I have one image for multiple product. I am importing images from a subdirectory of files, the field is in the csv: `public://productimages/PRODNUM.jpg`.
It is working very nice, but when I use the same photo for multiple images it is makes a new image for every product. (PRODNUM.jpg PRODNUM_1.jpg PRODNUM_2.jpg PRODNUM_X.jpg)

I like to use the same image for same products if the name is same.

I tried `filefield path` `filefield source` but not helped. If it possible I do not want to use the media module.

Comment: I think I solved this problem, but not a nice solution. I patched the sites/all/modules/feeds/plugins/FeedsParser.inc in line 441 to
$file = file_copy($file, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

Answer (score 0):

If the images in the same place where the field is waiting for it the images will not multiple.